# What is the use of /usr/include directory?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, c

I'm very new to Ubuntu. I'm looking at the directory `/usr/include` it contains lot of header files. I know they have specified certain constants and other information that are used in Ubuntu. I'm confused with the use of it.

One of the directory inside is `linux/byteorder`. Which has two files:

```
big_endian.h  little_endian.h
```

I wonder why two files are needed? My machine will be either big endian or little endian right? Didn't ubuntu while installation didn't pick my system byte order? Does `/usr/include` is just same for all machines? What is the exact use of it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That folder includes the header files for C compilers. Such as "stdio.h", "stdlib.h" etc.

When you type header information in the C source file such `#include <stdio.h>` the compiler will look for the file in `/usr/include` directory by default.

`big_endian.h` and `little_endina.h` files are included, because though your computer may be of only one kind, you can cross-develop application for both architecture. So, you need both header file.

- [What is the meaning of the default directories in the Linux filesystem hierachy?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/933/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-default-directories-in-the-linux-filesystem-hierachy)
- [See this link about gcc's searching preference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)
- [Another page explaining the /usr/include directory](http://web.archive.org/web/20100511072431/http://bid.ankara.edu.tr/yardim/linux.install.guide/node116.html) (The original link was removed, this is the one that's cached by archive.org)

Comment: Your third link needs to be translated and then it is reported as broken.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix of course it wasn't like that before. Must have changed. I'll remove it. The older page can be accessed via cache here http://web.archive.org/web/20100511072431/http://bid.ankara.edu.tr/yardim/linux.install.guide/node116.html

Answer (score 4):

These files are needed when you compile programs, be that a software package you need to compile manually or your own programs. They are included in the C code such that you can use the functions defined there. Don't worry about them if you don't code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you may decide to develop a cross platform app.

And when you write program for the other machine which is different endian than yours. Then may be these files are used to compile such programs. :)