# Where should an Ubuntu admininstrator (user) mount directories not established by the distribution?

Tags: mount, directory, directory-structure

I have read the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy

I found an operative statements to be

For /mnt it notes some distributions create automount directories for floppies and cdroms there (and one should probably not assume that list is complete in terms of distributions using /mnt or the directories they use, imho)

for /srv the LHS states

```
Distributions must take care not to remove locally placed files in these directories without administrator permission.
```

I also looked these up

[Why have both /mnt and /media?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22215/why-have-both-mnt-and-media)

[What does/will the directory /srv contain?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166555/what-does-will-the-directory-srv-contain#)

It appears (largely through observation) that ubuntu performs automounts into /media/{administrator/user} (if true, better than /mnt)

It also appears that Ubuntu appears to have left /mnt entirely to the user or administrator to control -- (in total compliance with the LFH , imho, and if true, the answer I seek).

/srv according to the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy has shared control by the distribution and the administrator/user.

Now I want to create directories on a user data for a file server, user media for a media center, directory for source control, etc.  Many of these directories will be on devices other than the boot device

If ubuntu as I have surmised does not use /mnt for anything that could be the best location for my various subdirectories (as they will be mounted and will not conflict with ubuntu's distribution directories).

/srv if not used by ubuntu, or if there are recommended names for administrators/users in the /srv directory may be a good choice too even though these directories will be mounted.

Basically my question is which is the better directory for administrator/user directories to avoid potential conflict with directories created by the distribution when required?

Thanks in advance for considering this.

Answer (score 2):

> It appears (largely through observation) that ubuntu performs automounts into /media/{administrator/user} (if true, better than `/mnt`)

- `/mnt` used to be for fixed disks (hdd, sdd) but it is discarded nowadays in favor for user defined partitions (ie a mountpoint in `/`).
- `/media` for removable media (cd, dvd, bd, usb)

> `/srv` if not used by ubuntu

Not by default; it is for services to use and those you install as extra software. `/srv` has a couple of note in the FHS:

> One method for structuring data under `/srv` is by protocol, eg. `ftp`, `rsync`, `www`, and `cvs`
>
> Data that is only of interest to a specific user should go in that users' home directory. If the directory and file structure of the data is not exposed to consumers, it should go in `/var/lib`.

So the use case for the directory is limited as it as.

A couple of examples: `cgi` scripts, ftp downloads and such.

> Now I want to create directories on a user data for a file server, user media for a media center, directory for source control, etc. Many of these directories will be on devices other than the boot device

You can use `/srv/` for that. The idea is to create a sub directory based on protocol in there.

I would use a different disk or partition for this though and create a new directory in `/` specifically for this that is used as a mount point with a name you make up. 100% guaranteed no default is going to touch that mount point (Ubuntu/Linux will stick as close to the FHS layout)

Comment: Thanks -- that covers it completely.